# Regular expression that finds and replaces a long string of words

Tags: regex, insert, whitespace

I am new to Regular Expressions.

What is the expression that would find a long string of words that begin with a 3-digit number and place spaces at the beginning of capitalized words:

REPLACE:

```
013TheBlueCowJumpedOverTheFence1984.jpg
```

WITH:

```
013 The Blue Cow Jumped Over The Fence 1984
```

Note: removes the .jpg at the end

This will save me ooooodles of time.

Comment: which language? A digit is not a capitalized letter. Do you also want to put spaces before it, as in 1984?

Answer (score 1):

I would not use regular expressions for this task. It's going to be ugly and hard to maintain.  A better approach would be to loop through the string and rebuild the string as you go based on your input.

```
string retVal = "";
foreach(char s in myInput){
    if(IsCapitol(s)){
        reVal += " " + s;
    }
    //insert the rest of your conditions
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not telling you - I am using a Wordpress plugin named Search Regex so this won't be possible. Thank you so much though!

Answer (score 0):

try use this regular expression `\d+|[A-Z][a-z]*`

it will collect all matches, and you must join them with spases

Comment: This evening I will have to back up the database first and then use the plugin Search Regex. I'll let you know the results. The helpfulness of this community continues to amaze me and it is something I am truly thankful for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

match:

```
'[A-Z][a-z]*'
```

replace with

```
' \0'
```

Note that this doesn't put a space before 1984, and it doesn't remove .jpg.
You can do the former by matching on

```
'[0-9]+|[A-Z][a-z]*'
```

instead. And the latter by removing it in a separate instruction, for example with a regexp replacement of '`\.jpg$`' with ''

Note that `\`'s need to be written as `\\` in many languages.

Comment: What final regex? If you want one regex to match multiple times, you cannot combine it with one that must be replaced with something else. So there are two regex's: one for the spaces, and one for stripping the extension.

Comment: This evening I will have to back up the database first and then use the plugin Search Regex. I'll let you know the results. The helpfulness of this community continues to amaze me and it is something I am truly thankful for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This will need two operations since the replacement is different for each.

The first:

```
/(((?<![\d])\d)|((?<![A-Z])[A-Z](?![A-Z])))/
```

Replace with: `' $1'` (note the space)

Will put spaces between the words. The second:

```
/\s*(.*)\s*\..*$/
```

Replace with: `'$1'`

Will remove trailing spaces and the extension.

The first expression can be taken into parts: `(?<![\d])\d` finds a digit not preceded by another digit, the second: `((?<![A-Z])[A-Z](?![A-Z]))` finds an uppercase letter not preceded or followed by an uppercase lettter.

You'll likely have more rules that you will want to incorporate into this, such as how are you dealing with the string: `'BackInTheUSSR.jpg'`?

**Edit**: This should handle that example:

```
/(((?<![\d])\d)|((?<![A-Z])[A-Z](?![A-Z]))|((?<![A-Z])[A-Z]+(?![a-z])))/
```

Comment: This evening I will have to back up the database first and then use the plugin Search Regex. I'll let you know the results. The helpfulness of this community continues to amaze me and it is something I am truly thankful for! Thank you so much!